# Animation turns in to spaghetti

Tags: animation, armature, bones, keyframes, pose-mode

Made an animation the day prior and put it in the Unity game engine, and it works fine, the next day I took a look at the same animation in Blender and it went completely crazy, I can describe it as turning into spaghetti, this only accrued with a few animations I made.

The first image is yesterday and the second is today, I want to know if anyone at all has any ideas of how this happened and solutions to save the animations.

[image: Yesterday][image: Today]

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos can you turn the deleted "answer" into a comment? the user does not have enough reputation points to comment.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking and saying.